# How to track specific item as part of a kit

Tags: ms-access

Here is my situation. I have over 50 boxes each with a unique ID number. That number is tracked for inventory purposes. My problem is that inside each box there is one specific part that is tracked independently of the box. What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to track the serial number from the part and link it up to which box it goes in such that the following rules are followed:

1. Each box cannot contain more than one primary part
2. Not every box has a primary part (some were broken and never replaced)
3. If a primary part needs to be moved from one box to another the original box it was taken from shows up as having no primary part.

I thought this would be fairly easy to accomplish with MS Access since it is already deployed across the network, but I am having a hard time preventing multiple boxes from being assigned the same primary part. If I just put the part SN as a field in the same table as the box then I have to remember to change 2 things any time one of the parts moves.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Box ID against the primary part, instead of the primary part serial number against the box. To see what's in the box you need to search the Primary Part table for the Box ID. If you move which box a part is in, you just update it once.

You could make a unique index on BoxID as well to ensure that there are never 2 primary parts in the same box.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Assigning the unique index halfway achieves what I want to do. I can now no longer assign multiple primary parts to one box. Now I need to make a primary part move without needing to remove it from the box it is currently in before assigning it to a new box. Right now when I attempt to move the part to a new box it throws an error because that change will not be unique.

Comment: How many new parts can you have that aren't in a box?

Comment: No limit to parts without a box. I have more boxes (5 boxes that have no primary component). In order to complete a kit and issue to a customer I often move one of the parts to a new box and then sign that box out to someone for use. Also any time a primary part fails I do a one for one swap with the user to ensure minimal interruption to services while I fix the broken one. The key here is that no one besides me cares about what is in the box. The customer only cares about what box they have and that each box has 1 primary component and all accessories.

Comment: In that case do the same, but make the index non-unique. It will allow multiple parts to be in the same box, but it won't allow 1 part to be in multiple boxes.